# OSGI application using IPOJO

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, ipojo

I am new in programming OSGI application I have successfully use KNOPFLERFISH and felix gogo but my supervisor ask me to use IPOJO, what is the difference between IPOJO and the others? Would you help me to start!

Comment: Have you tried to google for each of the terms?

Comment: i did'nt found any negative point , i am searching for a raison that make me choose the best one of them i find that KNOPFLERFISH is easy to use   it has an interface

Comment: Knopflerfish is an OSGi framework. Felix gogo is a shell and ipojo is a dependency framework. That is like comparing apples with bananas and oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPOJO is more secure than other ,it contains the dependancies of interaction between the Bundles , So you are not obliged to found the dependancies by your self , IPOJO is more easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

To help you compare the different solutions, the following presentation can be useful:

http://www.slideshare.net/mfrancis/the-ultimate-dependency-manager-shoot-out-x-uiterlinden-s-mak

Answer (score 1):

iPOJO has advantages to build dynamic applications, e.g., a service can be implemented by many components. these component can be deployed and active. With iPOJO, you can select dynamically the services if you want.

For more detail, you can entre in the iPOJO site.